# Trigger created but not working after insertion of new entry. ORA-04091 error shown

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I have created trigger to insert data into another table based on entry from another table. The trigger is created but after entering value in the table, below error is received.

> ORA-04091: table OOMUSER.EMTN_EVC_PAIR_STATUS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
>
> ORA-06512: at "OOMUSER.PORTSTATUSUPDATE", line 22
>
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'OOMUSER.PORTSTATUSUPDATE'

```
DROP TRIGGER OOMUSER.PORTSTATUSUPDATE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER OOMUSER.PORTSTATUSUPDATE
AFTER INSERT 
ON OOMUSER.EMTN_EVC_PAIR_STATUS     FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
LEGA VARCHAR2(20);
LEGB VARCHAR2(20);
ACTIVEPAIRA NUMBER;
ACTIVEPAIRB NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT EELA.CPE_PORT_SERVICE_ID INTO LEGA FROM EMTN_EVC_LEG_A EELA WHERE EELA.EMTN_EVC_PAIRID = :NEW.EMTN_EVC_PAIRID;
SELECT EELB.CPE_PORT_SERVICE_ID INTO LEGB FROM EMTN_EVC_LEG_B EELB WHERE EELB.EMTN_EVC_PAIRID = :NEW.EMTN_EVC_PAIRID;

IF (:NEW.STATUS = 'Active' OR :NEW.STATUS = 'Planned') 
THEN    
    INSERT INTO OOMUSER.EMTN_ETN_CPE_PORT_STATUS
        (CPE_PORT_SERVICE_ID,STATUS,STATUS_START_DATETIME)
        VALUES(LEGA,:NEW.STATUS,SYSDATE);
    INSERT INTO OOMUSER.EMTN_ETN_CPE_PORT_STATUS
        (CPE_PORT_SERVICE_ID,STATUS,STATUS_START_DATETIME)
        VALUES(LEGB,:NEW.STATUS,SYSDATE);

ELSIF(:NEW.STATUS = 'Rejected' OR :NEW.STATUS = 'Cancelled')
THEN
    SELECT COUNT(OVEDS.EMTN_EVC_PAIRID) INTO ACTIVEPAIRA FROM OOM_VW_EMTN_DUALEVC_STATUS OVEDS WHERE OVEDS.EMTN_EVC_PAIRID IN 
    (
        SELECT EELA.EMTN_EVC_PAIRID FROM EMTN_EVC_LEG_A EELA WHERE EELA.CPE_PORT_SERVICE_ID = 
        (
            SELECT EELA.CPE_PORT_SERVICE_ID FROM EMTN_EVC_LEG_A EELA WHERE EELA.EMTN_EVC_PAIRID = :NEW.EMTN_EVC_PAIRID
        )
    ) AND UPPER(OVEDS.STATUS) IN ('ACTIVE','PLANNED'); 
    
    IF(ACTIVEPAIRA = 0) 
    THEN
        INSERT INTO OOMUSER.EMTN_ETN_CPE_PORT_STATUS
            (CPE_PORT_SERVICE_ID,STATUS,STATUS_START_DATETIME)
            VALUES(LEGA,:NEW.STATUS,SYSDATE);
    END IF;
    
    SELECT COUNT(OVEDS.EMTN_EVC_PAIRID) INTO ACTIVEPAIRB FROM OOM_VW_EMTN_DUALEVC_STATUS OVEDS WHERE OVEDS.EMTN_EVC_PAIRID IN 
    (
        SELECT EELB.EMTN_EVC_PAIRID FROM EMTN_EVC_LEG_B EELB WHERE EELB.CPE_PORT_SERVICE_ID = 
        (
            SELECT EELB.CPE_PORT_SERVICE_ID FROM EMTN_EVC_LEG_B EELB WHERE EELB.EMTN_EVC_PAIRID = :NEW.EMTN_EVC_PAIRID
        )
    ) AND UPPER(OVEDS.STATUS) IN ('ACTIVE','PLANNED'); 
    
    IF(ACTIVEPAIRB = 0) 
    THEN
        INSERT INTO OOMUSER.EMTN_ETN_CPE_PORT_STATUS
            (CPE_PORT_SERVICE_ID,STATUS,STATUS_START_DATETIME)
            VALUES(LEGB,:NEW.STATUS,SYSDATE);
    END IF;
    
END IF;

END;
/
```

Comment: Inside of your trigger you do a couple of inserts. Does any of these tables have a trigger that fires on these inserts? And if so is there a select statement somewhere inside these triggers on emtn_evc_pair_status?

Comment: Read this. https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora04091.php

Comment: @Rene : no this is the only trigger on emtn_evc_pair_status table

Comment: @Utsav : I am not using the table(EMTN_EVC_PAIR_STATUS) on which trigger is running, in any queries

Comment: Check if `OOMUSER.EMTN_ETN_CPE_PORT_STATUS` have no Trigger which is inserting on `EMTN_EVC_PAIR_STATUS`

Comment: @Utsav : no there are no triggers at all on OOMUSER.EMTN_ETN_CPE_PORT_STATUS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message ayss that line 22 is the problem:

> ORA-06512: at "OOMUSER.PORTSTATUSUPDATE", line 22

Figuring out the line numbers of Trigger Body source code is not a precise science, especially when it has been pasted into StackOverflow, but it seems plausible that `line 22` indicates this line as the trouble:

```
SELECT COUNT(OVEDS.EMTN_EVC_PAIRID) INTO ACTIVEPAIRB FROM OOM_VW_EMTN_DUALEVC_STATUS OVEDS WHERE OVEDS.EMTN_EVC_PAIRID
```

Is `OOM_VW_EMTN_DUALEVC_STATUS` a view, by any chance? If so, what tables does it depend on? My guess is `EMTN_EVC_PAIR_STATUS` features in there.

Comment: great. OOM_VW_EMTN_DUALEVC_STATUS is a view and it is dependent on EMTN_EVC_PAIR_STATUS table for data

Comment: anything that can be done to avoid this issue and also able to use this same view?

Comment: Not in a trigger, at least not easily. Obviously I don't understand the business logic you're trying to implement but it seems too complicated for a trigger. You should consider having a stored procedure to handle everything, including the triggering insert(s).